# Keras' model.predict() give an output in binary with softmax activation layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained InceptionResNetV2 from Keras with 40 classes and tested it using model.evaluate(); it was all good. But when I try to use model.predict() with a single image, I get an output like

`[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]` instead of a probability distribution.

Colab for error reproduction: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BTuNdwQK5CqaggBVAfJ1cTTR2Qp0GH6v?usp=sharing

[Model Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zX4Q.png)

Comment: please provide some code to reproduce...

Comment: edited question for the link @DavidThery

Comment: output layer needs activation, seems like it is missing and you just have a dense layer there. example like `activation='sigmoid'`

Comment: Shouldn't the output activation be 'softmax' when dealing with multiple classes?

Comment: yes, that's right. is your prediction accurate? if not seems like it's overfitting.  few things you can try: 1st review of the data you are feeding, 2nd on the training set, how the model is behaving? is it possible to show code on, how you are transferring the pre-trained weights? because your colab start from loading the model. i think need the full picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preprocessing the testing image with the Keras' built-in function helped in my case.

```
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import preprocess_input 
img_batch = preprocess_input(img_batch)
```

Answer (score 0):

21 is the index of the predicted class and you have 40 classes. If you have a list of your classes ie class_list[etc...] the the class is class_list[21]

Comment: I'm actually testing for a class which is class_list[0], and the image used was the one used for testing, please refer with the colab link

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `model.predict`, used `model.predict_proba` like this:

```
predict_proba(image, batch_size = 32, verbose = 1)
```

Comment: It gave the same results as earlier